# Angular 2 specific code in innerHTML

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I am building an Angular 2 mobile site on top of an older system from which I am served html from a web service.

In the served html there are links which will go to angular pages within my new app. I am currently using `<div [innerHTML]="serverDoc"></div>` to render the html.

Is it even possible to add a `(click)="goToPageX()"` in my server-side html and then get it to call a function in my type script class so that I can route the user to the right page via angular 2 router?

Is there a need to do so? Will plain links to the right url keep the navigation history intact even when not going through angular 2 router?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the router, you can add the `routerLink` directive to your buttons or links. You need to set up your routes beforehand.

```
<button routerLink="/link/toPage">Go to page</button>
```

If you want to route programatically, you can use the Router's navigate function.

```
import { Router } from @angular/router

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<button (click)="goToPage()">Go to page</button>'
})
export class AppComponent { 
    constructor(private _router: Router){ }

    goToPage(){
        this._router.navigate("/link/toPage");
    }
}
```

Read more at angular2's [router documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

-------------- Edit --------------

If you want to go to a link using a button, you can do it in javascript by using `window.location.href`. This works for linking to angular locations too, if you're outside of it to begin with.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function goToPage(){
                window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="goToPage()">google</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: These alternatives won't work since I am adding the html into the [innerHTML] of a component, from which I am not able to connect to the angular code. Which anwsers my first question about adding the (click) to my html, it won't work...

Comment: No, `(click)` can't work because that would require angular to be running. If you want to go to a page using a button in plain html/js, you can do so using `window.location.href`. I edited my answer to include a simple example.